# Why the order of a series can't be changed

Tags: sequences-and-series, order-of-integration

Why do the infinite series
$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-... \neq 1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}...$ ?
While when integrating it's possible to change the order of the integration?

Comment: It's not always possible to change the order of integration.

Comment: The series does not converge absolutely , therefore the order of the summands is crucial.

Comment: Integrals and sums have a lot in common, but note that an indefinite integral (with limit $\pm \infty$) is computed via a limiting process and will run into similar issues if you start rearranging pieces of the original function in a different order (thus giving yourself a different function to integrate)

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of the Riemann Rearrangement theorem? You can certainly do this if you know that your series converges absolutely.

Note that your series does not converge absolutely: If you take the absolute value of each term, then you have harmonic series, which is a divergent one. Hence, you cannot do what you wanted to do. :p